# Range selection, difference betwin EXCEL macro vs VisualStudio Addin

Tags: excel, vsto

I've a Excel sheet with a lot of values. If I make a filter for selecting the values and I copy them to another sheet all works with a Excel macro, something like this...

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$109").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="CV2"
Range("F56:F69").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("F116").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

If I try to do the same operation in a Add in I use :

```
 Dim CodeDrawingCell As Excel.Range = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.RangeSelection
```

But in this second case the , I can't take only the selected and filetered values...where I'am in wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Range("A1", "M109").AutoFilter(Field:=2, Criteria1:="CV2")

Dim src As Excel.Range = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Range("F56", "F69")
src.Copy()

Dim dest As Excel.Range = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Range("F116")
dest.PasteSpecial()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but perhaps I explained badly. With hhe excel macro I just wanted to show the operations that I do. Actually I have to recover the cells that the user has selected. If the filter is active, with macro I get still visible selection, while with the addin get the limits of the range from the first to the last cell in the range also not visible. I can not know in advance what will be the range that the operator will select.